# Fastlane Gym - Temporary Build Directory

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I have been using fastlane (2.24.0) gym for IOS builds (Xcode Command Line Tools xcode-select)

Is there a built-in method which I could use to ensure that I am building from a stable environment?  I like to submit the build and use the time while it is building to carry on working.

I do **not** want to build from the **git repository** but from my own machine.

I could copy the directory either manually or in the fastfile script and build from there but I thought perhaps that there was a method or parameter I could use to avoid this step.

Answer (score 0):

you mean that you want to keep on editing the source code while *gym* is building your app? - saddly i don't see any option to this, without copying the whole project folder.

if you just wan't to ensure the build fragments to not overlap you can use/set `derived_data_path` on *gym*

however there are a couple of issues on running xcode (building) - multiple times in parallel.
the only sane way to build and carry on working is to offload the building/packaging process to any sort of CI.

Comment: I am not adverse to copying the folder, I just hoped there was a built-in function rather than scripting it manually

Comment: the Fastfile - is just a normal ruby file so you could to the copy thing directly in your fastfile using standard ruby `File.*` operations